# Save all data of the Tab Stack Trace, of various HTTP connections of the Network Panel on Firefox DevTools, in file?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

The option "Save All as HAR" of Network Panel on Firefox DevTools save all, excluding data of Stack Trace, as shown in the following figure.

[Tab Stack Trace of Network Panel on Firefox DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk0Ln.png)

How do I download the data of the Stack Trace to a file?

Comment: When you select `Save All as HAR`, Firefox's download/save window shows up, you can select either Save File or Open With option. this doesn't help?

Comment: No. This file HAR not contain Stack Trace data.